# site column across collections

Tags: site-column

What I'm looking for: At root level of collection "A", I have created a site column named "Organization". I'd like this same column to be available over in collections "A1" and "A2", which I consider to be children of collection "A".

I have looked at plenty of similar or somewhat-similar questions, but none of them seemed to really fit.

This is for SharePoint 2010 Enterprise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could utilize the content syndication hub and create a site column there. Add it to an item content type and syndicate that content type to all site collections. At which point that column should become an option to use in all site collections. This is in theory of course but it should work.